# create an array in which every position represents an element of enum

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have this class. I would create an array ex. `Categoria[] cat` in which every place is represented by a letter of the enum type. So for example `cat[0=A], cat[1=B]` etc. How can I do this?

```
public class Categoria {

public enum LetteraCategoria{

    A,B,C,D,E,F;

    public static String getVerbose(){
        return "";
    }
}

private LetteraCategoria categoria;

private Hashtable<String,Autovettura> listaauto;

public Categoria(LetteraCategoria categoria){

    this.categoria = categoria;

    listaauto = new Hashtable<String,Autovettura>();
}

public LetteraCategoria getCategoria() {

    return categoria;
}

public Hashtable<String, Autovettura> getListaauto() {

    return listaauto;
}


}
```

Comment: unfortunately no one understood what I'm looking for to explain. I would create an array in which every position is an object Categoria and every position of array is A,B,C,D,E,F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
cat[LetteraCategoria.A.ordinal()]
```

Comment: Maybe it's the think I' looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your Enum

```
public enum LetteraCategoria{

    A,B,C,D,E,F;

    public static String getVerbose(){

        return "";
    }
}
```

---

Your Array

```
LetteraCategoria[] arr = new LetteraCategoria[3];
arr[0] = LetteraCategoria.A;
arr[1] = LetteraCategoria.B;
.
.
```

---

**Better Way**

Better to have an `ArrayList` and use `values()` method on enum and just iterate through result and keep adding it into the `List`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean array indexed with enum? If so, you should consider using [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

```
Map<LetteraCategoria, Categoria> cat = new EnumMap<LetteraCategoria, Categoria>(LetteraCategoria.class);
```

Then you can access your categories like `cat.get(LetteraCategoria.A)`.

Internally it is implemented more effective than ordinary HashMap.

Comment: This would be the best solution unfortunately I have to use only an array

Answer (score 0):

Use `values()`:

```
final LetteraCategoria[] tmp = LetteraCategoria.values();

final String[] stringValues = new String[tmp.length];

for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
    stringValues[i] = tmp[i].toString();
```